# Markdown that incorporates standard header

Tags: python, ruby, markdown

I would like to standardize my technical documents.  To simplify it, I'd like to use markdown but I also want it to incorporate a standard header and footer and versioning.

How can I include the header and footer in to each new document?

I would like something like this:

Header:

```
####My Company
![](http://image/file.jpg)
---
```

Footer:

```
---
<sup>File version:[version]</sup>
<sup>Compiled [date]</sup>
```

And then each tech document would be as such:

```
{include header.md}

- technical
- stuff
- and 
- other stuff

{included footer.md}
```

Then when converted to html or pdf it would just combine them all into one pretty document.

Alternatively if you can compile multiple documents into one out put like this:

```
markdown2pdf header.md body.md footer.md -o output.pdf
```

That would work too (syntax for that command was made up for example)

Is there a way to achieve this already using python or ruby, before I reinvent the wheel?

Comment: if you replace `marddown2pdf` with `pandoc` it will just work: `pandoc header.md body.md footer.md -o output.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on the specific implementation. Pandoc supports this through [template variables](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates). A good place to start hacking templates might be to take a look at the [pandoc-templates](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates) Git repository, and see what you can leverage within the [license](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/README.markdown).